# JPA/Criteria API - Like & equal problem

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I'm trying to use Criteria API in my new project:

```
public List<Employee> findEmps(String name) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Employee> c = cb.createQuery(Employee.class);
    Root<Employee> emp = c.from(Employee.class);
    c.select(emp);
    c.distinct(emp);
    List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

    if (name != null) {
        ParameterExpression<String> p = cb.parameter(String.class, "name");
        criteria.add(cb.equal(emp.get("name"), p));
    }

    /* ... */

    if (criteria.size() == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("no criteria");
    } else if (criteria.size() == 1) {
        c.where(criteria.get(0));
    } else {
        c.where(cb.and(criteria.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
    }

    TypedQuery<Employee> q = em.createQuery(c);

    if (name != null) {
        q.setParameter("name", name);
    }

    /* ... */

    return q.getResultList();
}
```

Now when I change this line:

```
            criteria.add(cb.equal(emp.get("name"), p));
```

to:

```
            criteria.add(cb.like(emp.get("name"), p));
```

I get an error saying:

> The method like(Expression, Expression) in the type CriteriaBuilder is not > applicable for the arguments (Path, ParameterExpression)

What's the problem?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Perhaps you need

```
criteria.add(cb.like(emp.<String>get("name"), p));
```

because first argument of `like()` is `Expression<String>`, not `Expression<?>` as in `equal()`.

Another approach is to enable generation of the static metamodel (see docs of your JPA implementation) and use typesafe Criteria API:

```
criteria.add(cb.like(emp.get(Employee_.name), p));
```

(Note that you can't get static metamodel from `em.getMetamodel()`, you need to generate it by external tools).

Comment: "name" here is the variable name of the parameter here? like :name in jpql?

Comment: @axtavt, how i can ignore case

Comment: will the result of the query be like `employee.name like '%<value>%'`? Is it possible to achieve `like '<value>%'`?

Comment: Of course, in `builder.like()` method, the second arg can be a String. So you can put sth like `Predicate like = builder.like(root.get(Employee_.name), "%joke%")`.

Answer (score 25):

Better: predicate (not `ParameterExpression`), like this :

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
if(reference!=null){
    Predicate condition = builder.like(root.<String>get("reference"),"%"+reference+"%");
    predicates.add(condition);
}
```

Comment: Also, you can add a replace in there to make it easier to use, for example:
Predicate condition = builder.like(root.<String>get("reference"),reference.replace("*", "%"));
This way, you can pass on * as special characters to represent the like behavior.

Answer (score 4):

It will work with a small addition of `.as(String.class)`:

```
criteria.add(cb.like(emp.get("name").as(String.class), p));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use :

```
personCriteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.like(
criteriaBuilder.upper(personRoot.get(Person_.description)), 
"%"+filter.getDescription().toUpperCase()+"%"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the proposals and although it did not give an error, it did not recover anything if I did not put all the expected text, in the end what was proposed by user3077341 worked for me but with the variant that I use '%' instead of "%", the like worked perfect.

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
if(reference!=null){
    Predicate condition = builder.like(root.<String>get("reference"),'%'+reference+'%');
    predicates.add(condition);
}
```

Comment: You mean a char instead of a String? Oh.